# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider in jasmine test when routeprovider service is injected in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, junit, jasmine

I have created an application in angular js, in which i am using ng-view for navigating templates, from routeProvider i am injecting a service called customerDetail to all templates. when i wrote a jasmine testcase for injecting customerDetail services into the CustomerReportController constructor, but i am getting

```
<failure type="">Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: customerDetailProvider &lt;- customerDetail
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**main/customerReport/main.spec.js**

```
describe('tsi', function() 
{
    var $scope, customerDetail;

    beforeEach(module('tsi.customerReport'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        CustomerReportController = $controller('CustomerReportController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            customerDetail: customerDetail
        });

    }));

    it('test CustomerReportController', inject(function() {
        expect(CustomerReportController).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module( 'tsi', ['tsi.customerDetail', 'ngRoute'])

.config(function(RestangularProvider, $routeProvider)
{
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/customer/service/detail');

    $routeProvider.when('/customerDetail',
        {
            templateUrl: 'main/main.tpl.html',
            controller: 'CustomerDetailController',
            resolve: {
                customerDetail: function(CustomerDetailService) {
                   return CustomerDetailService.getServiceDetail();
                }
            }
        }).when('/customerReport',
        {
            templateUrl: 'main/customerReport/main.tpl.html',
            controller: 'CustomerReportController',
            resolve: {
                customerDetail: function(CustomerDetailService) {
                   return CustomerDetailService.getServiceDetail();
                }
            }
        }).otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/customerDetail'
        });
})

.factory('CustomerDetailService', function(Restangular) {
    return {
        getCustomerDetail: function() {
            return Restangular.one('user/customerDetail').get().then(function(customerDetail) {
                return customerDetail;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**main/customerReport/main.js**

```
angular.module('tsi.customerReport', [])

.controller('CustomerReportController', function($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, customerDetail) 
{
    $scope.customerOrderDetails = customerDetail;
    :
    :
});
```

Comment: Is the main.js file added to the karma configuration file ?

Answer (score 0):

the same problem faced by me..
what I did was that I included all the services there in my js file. make sure all the services and providers are injected properly

here is an example code for jasmine unit testing.

```
 describe('UserService',function() {
   var scope, DataService, UserService, http, cookieStore;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($http, _DataService_) {

        http = $http;

        DataService = _DataService_;

    }));
    it('getProfilePicture', function () {
        http.post('/api/getProfilePicture', function (data) {

            expect(data).toBeDefined();

        });


    });

});
```

DataService is my service here

Comment: you should remove underscore from 'DataService'